# getting data from the form created with echo in php to another php

Tags: php, html, forms

My Code Looks Like:

```
<?php
    echo "
        <form action='form.php'>
            <input type='text' name='value'>
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
    ";
?>
```

And form.php is

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['value'];
?>
```

Error Code is:

> Notice: Undefined index: value in C:\xampp\htdocs\dynamic\form.php on line 2

Is it possible to get the value of field created using echo command?I don't want to use database,jQuery etc.

Comment: why are you using echo in your first file (where you are submiting form)? it can work without echo as well

Comment: Forms default to a GET method when POST isn't implied.

Comment: I'm trying to create a dynamic form using php only,this code was just to grab the idea.In my original code,there is one form using which already created one form and i want to create one more form for which i have been taking data in my 2nd form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the form method to `post`

```
<?php
    echo "
        <form action='form.php' method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='value'>
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
    ";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `method="post"` in form tag